# After editing a locally installed package in Heroku it resets

Tags: django, heroku

I've noticed that after the packages required written in "requirements.txt" were installed they are not installed anymore every time I push changes into the Heroku application I'm working, so I was assuming that those files were not modified anymore.

I then changed a file in /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/target_library/target_file but when I do git push the file goes back to its original state, although the library is not being installed again.

Is there a way to avoid libraries to be reseted or any workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the last answer.

> or fork the library on GitHub and install the forked version.

**Here are the few steps I've tested and it worked for me:**

1- Fork the package repo on `GitHub`.

2- Edit it and change whatever you need.

3- Now remove the original package name from your `requirments.txt` and replace it with `git+https://github.com/you-github-username/forked-edited-package.git`

**Now it should simply install the edited package to your Heroku dyno when you deploy the project**

Comment: Can I delete the forked repo from my GitHub after that?

Answer (score 0):

No this can't possibly work. Heroku will always install the packages directly from PyPI and won't know anything about your modifications. I don't know why you say they aren't installed again - on the contrary, they are.

Are you sure you really need to do this? It's a fairly unusual thing to do. If you are sure you do, then the only thing to do is to either for the files into your own project, or fork the library on GitHub and install the forked version.

Comment: I need to do that because I need to change a configuration file of a library, and afterwards I'm forced to restart the app to make the changes visible. What made me thought that the libraries are not reinstalled it's just because it's not reflected on the terminal, as it was the first time. Is it then possible to add my own github link in the requirements.txt somehow or do I have to push it to Heroku everytime I deploy the code?